# Rails 4 Nested Validations not working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this model:

```
class CompetitionEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participants
  has_one :address
  has_many :music_programs

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :participants, :music_programs,
    :allow_destroy => true,
    :reject_if     => :all_blank

end
```

and this one:

```
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :competition_entry
  has_one :birthplace

  validates :name, :surname, :instrument, presence: true
end
```

Now the problem is that, if I create a new competition entry, it goes through.
But if I fill ONE field, i.e name, then it comes up with an error!

Why is this happening? It should fail when all are empty!

Answer (score 0):

When you use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, you are able to create the `participants` records at the same time that the `competition_entry` record, considering that the hash passed to `competition_entry.create` contains `participants_attributes`. When you pass only name, it validates the participant to be created and fail because it has no `surname` and `instrument`. When you leave all field empty, the behaviour should be the same, but it isn't because you explicitly set `:reject_if => :all_blank`.

`:reject_if => :all_blank` states that the `participant_attributes` hash should be ignored if it is `blank?`, which happens when you don't fill any field. What is happening then is that a `competition_entry` is being created without trying to create a `participant` because the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is just ignored.